# This is undefined em React Hooks

Tags: react, react-hooks

Olá, estou criando um sistema em JS utilizando react Hooks, porém me deparei com um problema, quando eu utilizo `<Route exact path ="/produto/:idProduto" component={Quiz}/>`

conseguimos captar o id com `const {id} = this.props.match.params` (armazenando dentro de uma variável)

porém isso funciona normalmente em um "class component" exemplo:

```
class Quiz extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {  }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const {id} = this.props.match.params
        console.log(id)
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                oi
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Quiz
```

neste exemplo é impresso no console o id que está na url, tudo certinho. porém quando utilizo react hooks, aparece "this is not defined" mesmo exemplo com hooks:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

function Exemplo(){

    useEffect(()=>{
        const {id} = props.match.params
        console.log(id)
    },[])

    return(
        <div>
            oi
        </div>
    )
}
export default Exemplo
```

erro:

> TypeError: this is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve receber `props` como parâmetro do *hook* (assim como você recebe ele no construtor da classe) e usá-lo sem o `this`:

```
function Exemplo(props){
  const {id} = props.match.params

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Obrigado mano, funcionou!! (tirei o this)